# Issue with picking multiple JSON

Tags: javascript, json, load, jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a script and "search" an id from it.

I have performed the following things

1. Have parametrize the "searcID" so that it can be picked from the "CSV_Data Config"
2. Have extracted the "key" from the URL through "Regular Expression Extractor" to provide it to the desired URL requiring "key", so that it can be dynamic

Now the issue is, since the script is recorded for one search id, in "/build-4.4.10.0/SECChecker/Search/Html?_dc=0.5557150364018139&Grid-Ajax", the last line of my script has a body of the one recorded "searchId".

The script runs and return for each thread this same result of JSON (that is present in the last line i mentioned), i want this too to be dynamic, how can i do that? Please guide

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parametrize the last request, you should use the following notation: ${**"var name"**} and use a [CSV manager.](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) [link2](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config)

for instance, if you want to parametrize the fist param of the body you should have something like this:

```
   {"SortField":"${var_name}",....
```

One thing, the dc param, part of the path, looks like a random used to avoid cache, so I use this to simulate the requests during the test:

```
.../Html?_dc=${__RandomString(15,0123456789)}&Grid-Ajax
```

This function returns a string which its length is 15 (1st param) and has a set of numbers (2nd param)

Hope It helps you.